# How to filter a spinner's string-array adapter?

Tags: android

There are two spinners , say spinner1 and spinner2, having both string-array adapters as their adapters. The business logic of the application is that spinner2 depends on the selected value of spinner1. So how to filter spinner2's data from the selected item of spinner1 ?
For example adapter 1 has strin-array :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="region"> // for the label displayed
        <item>Analamanga</item>
        <item>Itasy</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="region_id"> // this is for the actual value of the selected label
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Adapter 2 has string-array :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="district"> // for the label displayed
        <item>Central</item>
        <item>Boeny</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="district_id"> // this is for the actual value of the selected label
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: You just have to filter your String Array 2 according to the value selected on Spinner 1 and set a new Adapter on Spinner2.

Comment: how to filter the second string-array ?

Comment: It depends. What values do you have in each array? Could you show an example?

Comment: I edited my post to include some example data of the string-arrays.

Comment: So you need to change the whole array on Spinner 2, according to the selected value in Spinner 1, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "to change the whole array on spinner2" ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51444/discussion-between-joao2fast4u-and-pheromix)

Comment: @pheromix if you populate spinners using `ArrayAdapters` you can call `apater1.getFilter().filter("current_text_in_spinner_2");` should be simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `HashTable<Integer,ArrayList<String>>` to map your `RegionSpinner` and `DistrictSpinner` values.

This `HashTable` will have the positions of the selected items on `RegionSpinner` as keys and the `ArrayList<String>` that will feed your `DistrictSpinner` adapter as values.

Then, when you select an item on `RegionSpinner`, you set a new `FilterSpinnerAdapter` (an `Adapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter`) on `DistrictSpinner`, so the values on it change dynamically.

The `ArrayList<String>` that will be given to your new Adapter will be returned by your `HashTable`, according to the position you selected on `RegionSpinner`.

Here's the code:

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity{

Spinner spinnerRegion, spinnerDistrict;
int selectionCount=0;
Hashtable<Integer,ArrayList<String>> spinnerValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_buttons_activity);

    ArrayList<String> regions = new ArrayList<String>();
    regions.add("Analamanga");
    regions.add("Itasy");
    regions.add("ThirdRegion");

    ArrayList<String> analamangaDistricts = new ArrayList<String>();
    analamangaDistricts.add("Boeny");

    ArrayList<String> itasyDistricts = new ArrayList<String>();
    itasyDistricts.add("Central");

    ArrayList<String> thirdRegionDistricts = new ArrayList<String>();
    thirdRegionDistricts.add("District1");
    thirdRegionDistricts.add("District2");
    thirdRegionDistricts.add("District3");

    spinnerValues = new Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

    spinnerValues.put(0, analamangaDistricts);
    spinnerValues.put(1, itasyDistricts);
    spinnerValues.put(2, thirdRegionDistricts);

    spinnerRegion = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_region);
    if(spinnerRegion != null) {

        FilterSpinnerAdapter regionadapter = new FilterSpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_spinner_item, regions);

        regionadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerRegion.setAdapter(regionadapter);
        spinnerRegion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long itemId) {
                    FilterSpinnerAdapter newDistrictAdapter = new FilterSpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_spinner_item, spinnerValues.get(position));
                    newDistrictAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerDistrict.setAdapter(newDistrictAdapter);         
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
        });

    }

    spinnerDistrict = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_district);
    if(spinnerDistrict != null) {

        FilterSpinnerAdapter districtadapter = new FilterSpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_spinner_item, analamangaDistricts);

        districtadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDistrict.setAdapter(districtadapter);
        spinnerDistrict.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long itemId) {
                //do whatever you want here
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
        });

    }
}

public class FilterSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public FilterSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> ys) {
        super(context, resource, ys);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // - 1 so that the hint (last item) isn't shown
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

}
```

}

Update:
R.layout.layout_spinner_item is the layout for each drop_down item on the spinner. It contains a simple `TextView`. 
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinnerTitle" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:padding="5dp" android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I hope to have helped you. :D

Comment: Is `R.layout.layout_spinner_item` the layout of the Activity displaying the two spinners ?